# Trying to deploy rails application with mina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mina-deploy

I'm trying to deploy my application to my server in DigitalOcean.

If Log in to the server with credentials etc. I run bundle and I also make the application run. but with mina deploy it seems that bundle dont work.

I'm getting this error, that I dont know how to dig more and find whats is happening.

```
damaral@MacBook-Air-de-Diogo administrativo % mina deploy --verbose
-----> Creating a temporary build path"
-----> Fetching new git commits
-----> Using git branch 'main'
-----> Updating submodules
-----> Using this git commit
-----> Symlinking shared paths
-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
$ bundle install --without development test --path "vendor/bundle" --deployment
bash: line 147: bundle: command not found
! ERROR: Deploy failed.
-----> Cleaning up build
$ rm -rf "$build_path"
Unlinking current
$ rm -f "deploy.lock"
OK
Connection to 123.456.789.000 closed.
 !     Run Error
```

Does anyone knows how do I solve that? What is happening? Whats is causing the error?

Comment: Add ‘gem install bundler’ in your install file before calling ‘bundle install’

Comment: I have already connected directly to the server and installed the bundler.

Comment: the error message indicates your script cannot find it

Comment: Hi @dbugger, I already tried lot of things but I dont find a way to make it right. Could u help me with anydesk or something like?